# Jsoup returns empty element

Tags: jsoup

I'm fairly new to jsoup and can't seem to get a value from a element on a simple website. Trying to access a element with id=lastTrade and it corresponding value, which should be 7088.930 at this time.

```
String url = "http://bitcointicker.co/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element titleElement = doc.select("#lastTrade").first();
String title = titleElement == null ? null : titleElement.text();
System.out.println(title);
```

Comment: I guess there's something wrong with the Selector I'm using

Comment: Any way to add a debugger or print the doc and see whats coming up?

Comment: I've printed the Doc and searched for the id and found this: 
<div id="lastTrade"> 
  &nbsp;
</div>

Comment: Can you please try "div#lastTrade" instead of "lastTrade" and see if this fixes it.

Comment: thanks for the response. I just tried that and got the same result. Seems like every value I try to get is &nbsp, which is a blank?no? have no idea why though

Comment: As per your comment <div id="lastTrade"> &nbsp; </div> has null in it, you just pointed out, it means the issue is not with your code, initially it is null.

Comment: The chart where div#lastTrade gets filled is using JavaScript which can't be interpreted by a HTML parser (JSoup). Therefore the div you are selecting keeps containing "&nbsp;". For your attempt I suggest you to use: http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Have a look at the source, there are `script` tags with json data with all the trades. If it were me, I'd use jsoup to fetch and select the script block, and then use a json parser to parse the trade data. That'd be more efficient than running a full headless browser.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'll def give it a try!